# When does dotnet monitor sidecar pull the counters?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am running dotnet monitor as a side car of my dotnet web app (Using Kubernetes). Earlier I used it to get Event Counters and used prometheus to pull the metrics.

Below are the arguments that I passed:

> args: ["--no-auth", "--urls", "http://+:{{ .Values.service.metricsPort
> }}", "--configuration-file-path",
> "/app/config/dotnet-monitor-custom-config.json" ]

But now I am switching to open telemetry to emit these counters. I still want to keep the dotnet monitor sidecar for getting [/trace](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/api/trace-get.md) if needed.

Question is when does dotnet monitor pulls the counters from the web app? Is it when prometheus scrapes the /metrics endpoint? Or it keeps polling at [Global Polling interval](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/configuration/metrics-configuration.md#global-counter-interval)? If its global polling interval, can I set the value to 0?